# For Postman test script match string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, postman

Postman response is as below:
'''{
"error" : "validation error at #/test/TC_1594792360026/test"
}'''

I would like to verify this error message string. Digits are changed every time so I want to use it regex for that. I think regex [0-9]+ should work. But I don't know how to frame it in Postman.

I am using it in postman as below:
str t = "validation error at #/test/[0-9]+/test";

pm.expect(t).match(jsonData.error)

and Postman throws an error as "TypeError: e.exec is not a function"

Comment: Is there any other code you could include, perhaps a call to `exec`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The correct syntax to use regex in the assertion would be:

`pm.expect(jsonData.error).to.match(/validation error at #\/test\/TC_[0-9]+\/test/)`

Each assertion *getter* need to start with `.to` and you need to have a valid regex string inside the `.match()` method.

Comment: Thank you so much Danny Dainton, It is working perfectly fine for me. And yes, i missed to add '.to' while adding the question.

Comment: Please accept and upvote the answer to close this out. 

Comment: I have started using it recently so it is not publicly visible now. I'll surely do that once I am allowed.

Comment: Umm, you just need to accept my answer to your question. If it's something you are happy with.

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var year = currentDate.getFullYear() - age;
var month = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1; // Random month (1-12)
var day = Math.floor(Math.random() * 28) + 1;   // Random day (1-28)
// Ensure a valid date (e.g., avoid February 30th)
var maxDay = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
if (day > maxDay) {
    day = maxDay;
}

var dob = new Date(year, month - 1, day); // Subtract 1 from month because it's 0-indexed
return dob.toISOString().slice(0, 10); // Format as YYYY-MM-DD
```

// Specify the desired age
var desiredAge = 30;